# Fitting a large multirow-/column table on a page

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to create the following table in latex:

[image]

I am having a problem fitting this table to an A4 page. My idea was to make the text wrap in the column headers but after having searched for over an hour online and having seen many solutions, I have not been able to make it work.

This is the latex code I have right now (N.B. I have cut all but the first two rows to reduce the amount of code for readablity.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{discothesis}

\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}
\centering
\caption{Flushing efficiencies.}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{cp{0.082\textwidth} cp{0.082\textwidth} cp{0.082\textwidth} cp{0.082\textwidth} 
cp{0.082\textwidth} cp{0.082\textwidth} cp{0.082\textwidth} cp{0.082\textwidth} cp{0.082\textwidth} cp{0.082\textwidth} cp{0.082\textwidth} cp{0.082\textwidth}}
            
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Loca- \\ tion}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Reser- \\ voir}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Flushing \\ type}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Flushing \\ Year(s)}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{$V_{s,out}$ \\ $[m^3]$}} & \multirow{2}{*}{$V_{w,out} [m^3]$} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Volumetric \\ mixture \\ concentra- \\ tion $\sigma$ \\ $[ml/l]$}} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{Mean volumetric mixture concentration $\sigma_{,m} [ml/l]$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$V_{s,m,out} (FL) [m^3/a]$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$MAS (=V_{s,m,in}) [10^3 m^3/a]$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{*}{Flushing efficiencies $\eta_{f} [\%]$} \\
        
          &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & $\eta_{\sigma}$ & $\eta_v$ \\
        
        \multirow{5}{*}{CH} & \multirow{5}{*}{Ferden} & E   & 2018  &  96,000  &  2,285,000  & 42.01 & \multirow{5}{*}{47.97} & \multirow{5}{*}{112,667} & \multirow{5}{*}{50} & 4.20  & \multirow{5}{*}{225.3} \\
              &       & E     & 2016  &       120,000  & 4,030,000  & 29.78 &       &       &       & 2.98  &  \\
              &       & E     & 2014  &         60,000  &  2,803,000  & 21.41 &       &       &       & 2.14  &  \\
              &       & E     & 2013  &       160,000  &   3,796,000  & 42.15 &       &       &       & 4.22  &  \\
              &       & E     & 2012  &       240,000  &   2,297,000  & 104.48 &       &       &       & 10.45 &  \\

        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}
  \label{tab3:cp_values}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Right now, it gives me the following table (for some reason the `\eta_sigma` and `\eta_v` get pushed to the very right instead of being placed under the "flushing efficiencies"-cell):

[image]

Also, as you can see, the multirows with E's in them get pushed up into the column headers.

Thank you!

Edit 1: removed unnecessary packages

Edit 2: new table after having removed "c" from cp{0.082\textwidth}

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Where can we find the `discothesis` class file?

Comment: Thank you. I think it is a custom template. I could post it here in a moment.

Comment: Is there a reason for defining a total of 24 columns while only needing 12?

Comment: @leandriis Where did I define 24 columns?

Comment: @Bernard could you please help me out? how can I attach a .cls file to my post?

Comment: `cp{0.082\textwidth}` is two columns: One centered column that is as wide as its widest contents and a column that is as wide as 0.082\textwidth. Since you repeated `cp{0.082\textwidth}` 12 times, you get a total of 24 columns.

Comment: oh, I see. My understanding was that "c" the contents are centered horizontally in a cell and "p" placed the text at the top of the cell. I will correct that now and see what happens.

Comment: rather than provide discothesis it would be better to see if you can demonstrate the issue using `article` class (and simplify the example by removing every package not used in the example (which is almost all the packages you list)

Comment: @leandriis that is a great idea. thank you)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have changed the class to `article`, however it has not resolved the problem. @leandriis I removed the "c" from the cp{\textwidth}, and I now get a new table, but it is still broken (please see edit in the question)

Comment: the reason for using `article` class is not to solve the problem, simply to let us _see_ the problem as we can not run code that we don't have access to.

Comment: You are specifying very narrow columns `p{0.082\textwidth}` but then adding wide unbreakable text, where did you get the number 0.082 from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following table, I combined column 1 and 2 into a single column to save some space. Additionally, I also removed lengthy explanatory text from the column headers and placed it below the table. For the units and in order to improve the alignment of numbers inside of the columns, I used `siunitx`. Lastly, and since the table was still too wide for a portrait oriented page, I used `landscape` from the `pdflscape` package.

Since the originally used documentclass was not avialable, I used a regular `article` in combination with `geometry` for smaller margins. Depending on the actual size of your textblock and the font and font size in your document, you might need to so some further adjustments in order to make sure, the table fits into the available space.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}


\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Flushing efficiencies.}
\begin{tabular}{c 
                c 
                c 
                S[table-format=3] 
                S[table-format=4] 
                S[table-format=3.2]
                c 
                c 
                c 
                S[table-format=2.2] 
                c}
            
  \toprule
  \makecell{Reservior\\ (Location)}  
    & \makecell{Flushing \\ type} 
      & \makecell{Flushing \\ Year(s)} 
        & {\makecell{$V_{s,out}$ \\ {[\SI{E3}{\cubic\m}]}}} 
          & {\makecell{$V_{w,out}$  \\ {[\SI{E3}{\cubic\m}]}}} 
            & {\makecell{$\sigma_{s}$ \\ {[\si{\mL\per\L}]}}} 
              & {\makecell{$\sigma_{s,m}$ \\ {[\si{\mL\per\L}]}}}  
                & \makecell{$V_{s,m,out}$  (FL)\\ {[\si{\cubic\m\per a}]}} 
                  & \makecell{MAS  $(=V_{s,m,in})$\\  {[\SI{E3}{\cubic\m\per a}]}} 
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Flushing\\ efficiencies  $\eta_{f}$ {[\si{\percent}]}}} \\
                     \cmidrule{10-11}
        
     &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    {$\eta_{\sigma}$} & {$\eta_v$} \\
     
     \midrule
        
         \multirow{5}{*}{Ferden (CH)} & E   & 2018  &  96  &  2285  & 42.01 & \multirow{5}{*}{47.97} & \multirow{5}{*}{112,667} & \multirow{5}{*}{50} & 4.20  & \multirow{5}{*}{225.3} \\
                     & E     & 2016  &       120  & 4030  & 29.78 &       &       &       & 2.98  &  \\
                     & E     & 2014  &         60  &  2800  & 21.41 &       &       &       & 2.14  &  \\
                     & E     & 2013  &       160  &   3796  & 42.15 &       &       &       & 4.22  &  \\
                     & E     & 2012  &       240  &   2297  & 104.48 &       &       &       & 10.45 &  \\
    \midrule
                     & E     & 2016  &       120  & 4030  & 29.78 &       &       &       & 2.98  &  \\
                     & E     & 2014  &         60  &  2803  & 21.41 &       &       &       & 2.14  &  \\
                     & E     & 2013  &       160  &   3796  & 42.15 &       &       &       & 4.22  &  \\
    \midrule
                     & E     & 2012  &       240  &   2297  & 104.48 &       &       &       & 10.45 &  \\
    \midrule
                     & E     & 2016  &       120  & 4030  & 29.78 &       &       &       & 2.98  &  \\
                     & E     & 2014  &         60  &  2803  & 21.41 &       &       &       & 2.14  &  \\
    \midrule
                     & E     & 2013  &       160  &   3796  & 42.15 &       &       &       & 4.22  &  \\
    \midrule
                     & E     & 2012  &       240  &   2297  & 104.48 &       &       &       & 10.45 &  \\
                     & E     & 2016  &       120  & 4030  & 29.78 &       &       &       & 2.98  &  \\
     \midrule
                     & E     & 2014  &         60  &  2803  & 21.41 &       &       &       & 2.14  &  \\
                     & E     & 2013  &       160  &   3796  & 42.15 &       &       &       & 4.22  &  \\
                     & E     & 2012  &       240  &   2297  & 104.48 &       &       &       & 10.45 &  \\
                     & E     & 2016  &       120  & 4030  & 29.78 &       &       &       & 2.98  &  \\
    \midrule
                     & E     & 2014  &         60  &  2803  & 21.41 &       &       &       & 2.14  &  \\
                     & E     & 2013  &       160  &   3796  & 42.15 &       &       &       & 4.22  &  \\
                     & E     & 2012  &       240  &   2297  & 104.48 &       &       &       & 10.45 &  \\
                     & E     & 2013  &       160  &   3796  & 42.15 &       &       &       & 4.22  &  \\
    \midrule
                     & E     & 2012  &       240  &   2297  & 104.48 &       &       &       & 10.45 &  \\
        \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{11}{l}{\small $\sigma_{s}$ = volumetric mixture concentration,  $\sigma_{sm}$ = mean volumetric mixture concentration}\\
        \end{tabular}
  \label{tab3:cp_values}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you soooo much!!! You are a legend! I will have to look into the `siunitx` package. Also, I have never seen this \sisetup{}; going to read about it as well. Have a great day!!

Answer (score 2):

Avoid scaling tables it produces inconsistent font sizes and rule widths, I used `\small` here (although I don't know your actual text width, I assumed the same as article class A4 paper)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\small\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.3pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccrrrrrrrrr@{}}            
        \toprule
\makecell[t]{Loca- \\ tion}&
\makecell[t]{Reser- \\ voir} & 
\makecell[t]{type} &
\makecell[t]{Year} & 
\makecell[t]{$V_{s,\mathrm{out}}$ \\ $[m^3]$} &
$V_{w,\mathrm{out}} [m^3]$ & 
\makecell[t]{$\sigma$ \\ $[ml/l]$} & 
\makecell[t]{$\sigma_{,m}$\\ $[ml/l]$} & 
\makecell[t]{$V_{s,m,\mathrm{out}}$\\ $[m^3/a]$} &
\makecell[t]{$\mathrm{MAS} $\\ $\![10^3\!m^3/\!a]\!$} & 
\makecell[t]{$\eta_{f}$\\ $[\%]$} \\
        
          &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & $\eta_{\sigma}$ & $\eta_v$ \\
        
       CH & Ferden & E   & 2018  &  96,000  &  2,285,000  & 42.01 & 47.97 & 112,667 & 50 & 4.20  & 225.3 \\
              &       & E     & 2016  &       120,000  & 4,030,000  & 29.78 &       &       &       & 2.98  &  \\
              &       & E     & 2014  &         60,000  &  2,803,000  & 21.41 &       &       &       & 2.14  &  \\
              &       & E     & 2013  &       160,000  &   3,796,000  & 42.15 &       &       &       & 4.22  &  \\
              &       & E     & 2012  &       240,000  &   2,297,000  & 104.48 &       &       &       & 10.45 &  \\

        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
  \label{tab3:cp_values}

\raggedright

$\sigma$ = Volumetric mixture concentration

$\sigma_{,m}$ = Mean volumetric  mixture concentration 

$\mathrm{MAS} = V_{s,m,in}$

$\eta_f$ = Flushing efficiencies

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was going to add that the units would be better set with siunitx but leandriis has done that now already  so I'll leave this as is.

Comment: Thank you very much, David. This is a great solution, too. Also, kudos for the `\mathrm{}` suggestion. I had always wondered how to improve the subscript text in this way. I will upvote your answer as soon as I have 15 reputation))